# 502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.16.1 - for dash (plotly) application deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I have deployed a Dash (Plotly) application on AWS Beanstalk and when attempting to access the environment from AWS Beanstalk I get a '502 Bad Gateway' page. In addition to this, I'm observing several "failed (111: Connection refused)....." lines under the error.log as shown below.

```
var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2020/06/10 18:25:03 [error] 3863#0: *75 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 125.54.130.115, server: , request: "GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm", host: "15.106.221.125:80"
2020/06/10 18:42:24 [error] 3863#0: *77 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 125.54.130.115, server: , request: "GET /index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP", host: "15.106.221.125:80"
2020/06/10 18:55:34 [error] 3863#0: *79 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.6.232.9, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "15.106.221.125"..............
....................................
```

The nginx.conf file is shown below:

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

usernginx;
error_log/var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid/var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processesauto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32145;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

includeconf.d/*.conf;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
default     "upgrade";
    }

server {
listen80 default_server;
access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

client_header_timeout 60;
client_body_timeout   60;
keepalive_timeout     60;
gzipoff;
gzip_comp_level4;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript applic
ation/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

# Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
}
}
```

Would be great if someone could suggest a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with this today and resolved by modifying the file located in **.ebextensions/application.config** from:

```
option_settings:   
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: application:app
```

to:

```
option_settings:   
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: application:server
```

and then in my **application.py** file:

```
import dash

app = Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
...
```

Hope it helps!