# AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Dash plotly app) - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I am a newbie with programming and my boss would like me to deploy a dash plotly app on AWS elastic beanstalk. The code was deployed successfully but it is showing `502` bad gateway error.

> 502 Bad Gateway
> nginx/1.18.0

I tried to look into the /var/log/nginx/error.log and changed the port to `8000` but it still didn't work.

What is the solution for this error? Should I add Procfile and what should I add into that file? Thanks so much in advance!

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
2020/11/25 05:24:52 [error] 16068#0: *38 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:01 [error] 16068#0: *40 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.2.244, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:07 [error] 16068#0: *42 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:16 [error] 16545#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.2.244, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:22 [error] 16545#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "dashmonitoring1-env.eba-umwfi3nn.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2020/11/25 05:25:22 [error] 16545#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:22 [error] 16545#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "dashmonitoring1-env.eba-umwfi3nn.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://dashmonitoring1-env.eba-umwfi3nn.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2020/11/25 05:25:31 [error] 16545#0: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.2.244, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:37 [error] 16545#0: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:46 [error] 16545#0: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.2.244, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:25:52 [error] 16545#0: *14 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:26:01 [error] 16545#0: *16 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.2.244, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
2020/11/25 05:26:07 [error] 16545#0: *18 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.38.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "172.31.7.83"
```

Comment: "changed the port to 8000" - changed the port where?

Comment: Hi @Marcin - Thanks for your response! I changed the port in my application.py [if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True, port=8000)]

Comment: Isn't default port 5000? Anyway, if you ssh into the EB instance, can you confirm it works on localhost?

Comment: @Marcin The default is 8080 for me, but the error log suggest 8000, therefore i changed it. The dash app is working fine locally.

Comment: Will it be useful if I give you my last 100 log from Elastic beanstalk? I was deploying it manually.

Comment: Not really. I still will not know if your app works or not. Only you can check it from inside the instance.

Comment: Would you mind to guide me how to check it? Much appreciate it!

Comment: ssh to the instance and use `curl 127.0.0.1:8000` to check if you get correct response.

Comment: Apologies. It's a bit too technical there. Can I do it using the portal? I have tired EB CLI before, but I keep getting "ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid." Even I keep delete and generate new keys.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this solved the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300325/15524555 .
Basically my **.ebextensions/application.config** file wasn't pointing correctly to the dash app instance.